# pkgrm command + force command to delete all files and how to

Tags: solaris

when I removed the package - **Solaris_add-point** package  ( VIA pkgrm command )
I see from output the lines "shared pathname not removed"

please help me to understand what this mean

and if we can to force pkgrm command to remove the shared pathnames ?

example from pkgrm output

```
## Removing pathnames in class <none>
/etc/cn/scripts/fmt.ksh
/etc/cn/scripts <shared pathname not removed>
/etc/cn <shared pathname not removed>
/etc <shared pathname not removed>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means other packages are still installed that use those pathnames and they won't be
removed until all those packages are removed.

This is a good thing.   You really really really really do not want the `/etc` directory removed - that would kill the OS on the machine and make it impossible to boot.

Comment: I have crayze solution maybe need to mv the /etc to /etc.tmp and then to try again the pkgrm and return the /etc.tmp to /etc ???

Comment: Do **not** follow @Eytan's suggestion.  You will break your system and it will do nothing about the package database recording other packages using `/etc`.